# convert Div tag of my page into pdf in php while data is coming from databse

Tags: php, html, pdf

I want to convert the valve which are inside of the DIV tag to PDF file

```
<div id="container2">

                <?php
                    $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
                    mysql_select_db('account',$con);
                    $query1="Select * from e_bills";
                    $result=mysql_query($query1);
                        echo "<table  width='1000' border='5' cellpadding='2' id='bill'>
                        <tr>
                        <th style='border:1px solid black'><input type='checkbox'></th>
                        <th style='border:1px solid black'>BillNo</th>
                        <th style='border:1px solid black'>Amount</th>
                        <th style='border:1px solid black'>VendorName</th>
                        <th style='border:1px solid black'>Date</th>
                        <th style='border:1px solid black'>Paid</th>
                        <th style='border:1px solid black'>Pending</th>
                        <th style='border:1px solid black'>Action</th</tr>";



                //$res=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        //print_r($res);
                    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                            $pending=$res['bi_total']-$res['bi_paid'];
                            echo "<tr> <td style='border:1px solid black';>";
                            echo  "<input type='checkbox' class='ads_Checkbox' id='checkbox.$res[bi_billnumber]' value='$res[bi_billnumber]'>";
                            echo " </td>";
                            echo "<td style='border:1px solid black';>";
                            echo "B_".$res['bi_billnumber'];
                            echo "</td>";
                            echo "<td style='border:1px solid black';>";
                            echo $res['bi_total'];
                            echo "</td> ";
                            echo "<td style='border:1px solid black';><a style='color:red;text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer;'onclick='getdata1($res[bi_billnumber])'>";
                            echo $res['bi_vendername'];
                            echo "</a></td>";
                            echo "<td style='border:1px solid black';>";
                            echo $res['bi_date'];
                            echo "</td>";
                            echo "<td style='border:1px solid black';>";
                            echo $res['bi_paid'];
                            echo "</td>";           
                            echo "<td style='border:1px solid black';>";
                            echo "$pending";
                            echo "</td>";
                            echo "<td style='border:1px solid black';>";
                            echo "<input type='button' name='button' value='Edit' onclick='getdata($res[bi_billnumber])'>";
                            echo "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";

                    }
                echo "</table>";

                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
```

---

I have Used

```
<?php
include("/MPDF53/MPDF53/mpdf.php");

$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0); 

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;  // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first level of a list

$mpdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents('billdisplay.php'));

$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

But useful for only from static values not for the data which is coming from the database.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the dompdf for converting your html to pdf. It is so simple and it also take php code . [Dompdf Example](http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/examples.php)

Comment: yes all pages are static but you make a php page and put your dynamic value. before writing php code you have to enable php on dompdf_config.inc.php file DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP = true.

Comment: can you just elaborate plz because there is no such file as dompdf_config.inc and no such code or file available on your given site to download or copy.... thank you!!

Comment: download dompdf example http://speedy.sh/KhV4h/dompdf.zip and check just copy paste in your local server then open and test the examples.